# Doctrine Native SQL column conflicts with another column in the mapper

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm running into this problem getting a native query to map where the joined table has some columns where column name is same names from different table.  For sanity this is pretty much how tables look.

```
Addresses
    id
    latitude:float
    longitude:float
    street:string

Properties
    id:int
    latitude:float
    longitude:float
    address_id:int
    name:string


   <?php 

            $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
            $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MatrixBundle:CombinedListing', 'cl');
            $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('MatrixBundle:Address', 'a', 'cl', 'addresses', array('id' => 'address_id'));

            $qb = $this->_em->createNativeQuery("
                SELECT cl, 3959
                 * acos(cos(radians($lat))
                 * cos(radians(cl.latitude))
                 * cos(radians(cl.longitude) - radians($lng))
                 + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(cl.latitude)))
                 AS distance
                 FROM combined_listings as cl 
                 JOIN addresses as a on a.id = cl.address_id
                 WHERE a.state = :state
                 AND a.city = :city
                 ORDER BY distance $order
                 LIMIT $offSet, $max
                 ", $rsm);
            $qb->setParameters(["state" => $state, "city" => $city]);


            return $qb->getResult();
```

The error I get is

The column 'latitude' conflicts with another column in the mapper.

I've been searching all over for an answer, solution or workaround.  I hardly ever use native queries in doctrine but DQL doesn't support acos().  Has anyone else ran into this problem?

Comment: I think the problem is due to creating new object of `ResultSetMappingBuilder` and passing that to your nativeQuery which makes confiction. I would suggest to use `$this->$this->createNativeNamedQuery('YOUR_QUERY_STRING')`

Comment: Have you tried with $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');  add each field into  fieldTResult column.

Comment: @kapil I was trying to avoid doing that.  It seems there may be an doctrine extension bundle that will allow me to use cos(), acos() and sin() DQL functions.  That would be awesome because so far using native queries with in doctrine is a nightmare getting it to map.

Comment: @TimLieberman  Yes you are right. Doctrine2 has lots of complexity. It's hard for the developers to work with. Thanks for sharing your ideas about cos(), acos(), and sing extention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine not allowing ResultSetMappingBuilder to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580723/doctrine-not-allowing-resultsetmappingbuilder-to-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy of mine said he saw a question I asked a long time ago.  I checked it out and realized no one answered it.  The answer to this question is you have to use extensions.  Specifically these.  https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/src/Query/Mysql

Comment: That is not related to your question, when using nativequery you don't need extensions. Anyway, when having a problem like this `ResultSetMappingBuilder::COLUMN_RENAMING_INCREMENT` should be passed as a second parameter when creating the ResultSetMappingBuilder.

Comment: @TomásCot This is the real answer. It'd be helpful if you could post it as an answer, so it's more visible